# Xamarin.Forms Shared Project's Localization for UWP, iOS & Android

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms

While I try to manually add Resx files in the shared project of a Xamarin.Forms app that has UWP, Android & iOS, I get an error that the resx files  **aren't getting embedded**.

There is a shared project sample at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoLocalized/SharedProject/ but it doesn't cover UWP.

Do we have any localization solution for a SHARED project that covers UWP, iOS & Android, that I could refer to?

Thanks and regards,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't get the resx solution working for all three together (UWP, iOS & Android) for a **shared project type**, hence, I resorted to a **.NET standard library** as a shared project. It worked!

Comment: How you mean that "resorted to a .NET standard library as a shared project"? I have the same problem now, with a shared project type, and can't find a solution.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user1861065 Well, I created a shared project with .netstandard 1.4, and added AppResources.resx and AppResources.en-US.resx and other translation files. This url: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/ will help you better. With .netstandard 2.0, I haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 0):

By default when strongly-typed references to strings are generated, they will be `internal` to the assembly. This is because the default build tool for RESX files generates the **.designer.cs** file with `internal` properties.

Select the **AppResources.resx** file and show the **Properties** pad to see where this build tool is configure. The screenshot below shows the **Custom Tool: ResXFileCodeGenerator**

[image: image1]

To make the strongly-typed string properties `public`, you must manually change the configuration to **Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator**, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]